# Probability of choosing at least one sick people from a sample of ten when people being sick from the universe is 0,01%

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this on: 
"from our union we know that 0,01% is ill from some kind of a disease. What is the probability that from a sample of 10 people at least one is ill"

My  thinking so far has been something like this (X represents ill people from the sample).

$P(X\geq 1) = 1-P(X<1)^c = 1- (\frac{0,01}{100})^c \approx 9,995*10^{-4} $

Please tell me if I am like totally wrong, right ore something in between. All the possible feedback is welcomed

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least one person in the sample is equal to one minus the probability none are ill. If the samples are independent that that probability is $(1-0.001)^{10}$ so subtract that from $1$.